# Symfony2 Exceptions Break App

Tags: facebook, symfony

I'm using the Facebook PHP SDK with Symfony. Whenever I use the SDK I have it in a try and catch. However, Symfony breaks the app and throws up an error page. Normally this is really useful for debugging, but for the FB Exceptions I would much rather it let me handle it within the app itself.

Is there anyway for me to tell Symfony to just handle it like plain php?

Eg

```
$this->fb = new \Facebook($this->config);
$url = (string)
try {
    $result = $this->fb->api($url, 'POST');
    return $result;
}
catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    return;
}
```

I get a page from Symfony describing the exception, when I want to handle it myself.

Comment: More information such as the thrown error and the code would be helpful...

Comment: @SamyDindane I don't see how that would help for the question I'm asking but I added an example anyways

Comment: You still don't tell us about the exception that is thrown, but my guess is that it is different than `FacebookApiException`. Shouldn't it be `\FacebookApiException`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thrown exception isn't caught because it is different than `FacebookApiException`.
Since you're in a controller, you need to add a backslash to the exception's name: `\FacebookApiException`, so PHP would look for it in the global namespace instead of the controller's one.